# Is it possible to get a big personal loan for foreign investment?

Tags: united-kingdom, loans, home-ownership, european-union

I'm from the UK, working as a contractor for a US company, earning $30k+ annually, and I want to buy a house costing around $100k in a non-EU country. I need an investment visa to do this.

A mortgage for the house is not an option. I have considered this, and (a) the interest rates are very high in that country; and (b) without foreign investment I can't get an investment visa, which is a pretty important part for me.

How might I be able to get a personal loan of around $100k? 
Am I better off trying to get a business loan?

What other loan types might meet my need?

Comment: What are the investment visa requirements for the destination country?

Comment: Ad $30k is only Just over £21k which is absurdly low for an IT contractor id find a better paying job first.

Answer (score 7):

It can be very difficult, but not impossible. It will depend on :

- your working contract (fixed or permanent?).
- your bank policy (there    is huge difference between banks).
- you relation with your bank ( for new comer the bank is likely to refuse but if you are a good client in    the bank and knows the manager, they might accept).
- your marriage status
- down payment you can afford (% of the final price)

Go to ask several bank, they all have different policies.
If all the banks refuse, you can go to less conventional financing such as private ( family, friend,) or peer to peer lending.

But with 30K of salary in the UK, you need to pay all our expense (including rent) and you want to buy a house somewhere else? How much do you think you can pay every month to reinbouse the loan?

Comment: Good answer - the only thing it is possibly missing is a discussion of why this is more difficult given that the OP does not want a mortgage [the bank won't have collateral on the house, and therefore risk is higher].

Comment: the op says a contractor so its a temp /short term contract